# Check if the form elements is visible or not using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Below is the JavaScript function to check the if the all the elements present in the form is filled by the user.

```
var frm_elements = envelopes.elements;
        for (i = 0; i < frm_elements.length; i++) 
        {
            field_type = frm_elements[i].type.toLowerCase(); 
            switch (field_type)     
            {     
                case "text":        
                if(frm_elements[i].value == "" || frm_elements[i].value == null)
                {
                    if(frm_elements[i].style.display == "block")
                    {
                            alert("Enter All Text Box details");
                        return false;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                case "select-one":
                case "select-multi":         
                if(frm_elements[i].selectedIndex == -1)
                {
                    if(frm_elements[i].style.display == "block")
                    {
                        alert("Select Any Field From Drop Down");
                        return false;
                        break;
                    }
                }

                default:
                break; 
            }
```

the problem is I am using JavaScript method to hide some fields.
Below is the code which I am using it to achieve.

```
document.getElementById('stTxtMapName1').style.display = 'none';
```

For making it viewable, below piece of code is being used by me.

```
document.getElementById('stTxtMapName1').style.display = 'none';
```

So I have to check the fields only which is visible to the user ... So I am using this condition to check if it is visible.

```
if(frm_elements[i].style.display == "block")
                        {
                                alert("Enter All Text Box details");
                            return false;
                            break;
                        }
```

The above code is not working. Please provide any alternate way of checking this.

Comment: document.getElementById('stTxtMapName1').style.display = 'block';

for making it visible !

Comment: Generally speaking, form elements could be `inline` or `inline-block` but not `block`. Check `!= "none"` instead.

Comment: I even tried that ... that too didn't work ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the same implementation that jQuery uses and check for offsetHeight and offsetWidth, for example:

```
function isVisible(element) {
    return element.offsetWidth > 0 || element.offsetHeight > 0;
}

if(isVisible(frm_elements[i])) {
    // perform actions
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't change the display your element has empty `style.display` value. In order to check if element is visible use:

```
document.getElementById('elementId').style.display != "none"
```

So in your code:

```
if(frm_elements[i].style.display != "none")
```

---

I created a demonstration of your case in fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mattydsw/yz4duqfz/

Answer (score 0):

```
<form name="form1" id="form1" onsubmit=" return validate()" >

  <input type="text" name="abc" id="abc" style="display:none;"> <br />
  <input type="text" name="xyz" id="xyz" style="display:none;"> <br />
  <input type="text" name="pqr" id="pqr" style="display:block;"> 
  <input type="submit" name="submit"  >
  </form>
```

Javascript code

```
function validate()
{
    frm_elements = form1.elements;
     for (i = 0; i < frm_elements.length; i++) 
      {
          field_type = frm_elements[i].type.toLowerCase(); 
          switch (field_type)     
          {     
             case "text":        
             if(frm_elements[i].value == "" || frm_elements[i].value == null)
            {
                if(frm_elements[i].style.display == "block")
                {
                   alert("Enter All Text Box details");
                   return false;
                   break;
                }
            }
            case "select-one":
            case "select-multi":         
            if(frm_elements[i].selectedIndex == -1)
            {
                if(frm_elements[i].style.display == "block")
                {
                  alert("Select Any Field From Drop Down");
                   return false;
                   break;
                }
          }
          default:
          break; 
      }
   }
}
```

Try this it is work. I think you miss one brace.